# How to calculate frequency in the following question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics

A police car with a siren of frequency $8$ kHz is moving with uniform velocity $36 \mathrm{km}\, \mathrm{hr}^{-1}$ towards a tall building which reflects the sound waves. The speed of sound in air is $320 \mathrm{m}\, \mathrm{s}^{-1}$. The frequency of the siren heard by the car driver is?

- A: $8.50$ kHz
- B: $8.24$ kHz
- C: $7.75$ kHz
- D: $7.50$ kHz

Comment: Welcome to Phys.SE please read Phys.SE Help Center, it says that: "Do my homework"-type physics questions shouldn't be asked here: "example: "A 4kg ball is traveling at 8m/s in the x direction, how do I find...".

Comment: I asked my teacher he showed the solution and answer was option A but after i came back home i wasn't able to sove it again

Comment: The general expression for the apparent frequency (n") produced due to Doppler effect is 
n"= n(v+w–vL)/(v+w–vS) where ‘v’ is the velocity of sound, ‘w’ is the wind velocity ‘vL’ is the velocity of the listener, ‘vS’ is the velocity of the source. 
of sound and ‘n’ is the actual frequency of the sound emitted by the source., i got upto this point. after that i am getting stucked., this question is also not a do my homework type question because it was in one of my senior's book.

Comment: this is all what i have tried @GigiButbaia

Comment: So Doppler effect is described using $f=f_0(1+\frac{\Delta V}{c})$, speed of car is 36km/h (lets work in SI units) which is 10m/s, when sound wave is reflected relative speed is 20m/s, $c$ is speed of sound and $f_0$ is 8KHz, apply everything and you will get: $f=8(1+\frac{20}{320})=8.5$ so answer is 8.5 KHz

Comment: thnx but then write it as an answer, or shall i answer my own question after your explaination?

Comment: Actually the car driver hears two frequencies. First the sound he is moving with, second the reflected sound.

Comment: I will write it as an answer

Comment: @GigiButbaia shall i answer my question or would you care enough to post it as an answer

Comment: thnx okay then bye!!! @GigiButbaia

Comment: I mentioned it earlier also that it is not a homework question, it was in one of my seniors book while i was reading a little higher level, and when it comes to trying to solve on m own you can notice in my comments. @DumpsterDoofus

Comment: This is **not** off-topic. And if we consider what the OP is saying, this isn't even a homework question. It just needs to be modified a bit to suit the site's needs of good and productive questions...

Comment: I agree with @KvdLingen - when you are in a car with a siren blaring, you will hear the original frequency of the siren; it will be much louder than the sound of the reflected wave. Poorly worded question!

Answer (score 0):

So Police car is moving at $36$ $\mathrm{km/h}$ ($V_0$), The Frequency of siren is $8$ $\mathrm{kHz}$ ($f_0$) and speed of sound is $320$ $\mathrm{m/s}$ ($c$). In SI units Speed of police car is $10$ $\mathrm{m/s}$ ($V_0$). So Doppler effect is described using this equation:
$$
f=f_0\left(1+\frac{\Delta V}{c}\right)
$$
Where $f_0$ is siren frequency ($f_0=8$ $\mathrm{kHz}$), $c$ is the speed of sound ($c=320$ $\mathrm{m/s}$), and $\Delta V$ is relative speed of observer with source ($\Delta V= 2V_0=20$ $\mathrm{m/s}$). So now lets replace variables with numbers and calculate:
$$
f=8\left(1+\frac{20}{320}\right)=8.5\text{ $\mathrm{kHz}$}
$$
So Answer is $8.5$ $\mathrm{kHz}$